# Uninstall daemon tools lite

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I used daemon tools lite for installing visual studio 2010 iso file but now i want to remove unwanted softwares from my system. Do uninstalling daemon tools lite will affect my visual studio 2010 installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not, deamon tools only create a virtual disk, visual studio do not need the CD to be present in the drive when you run it.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't. Remove it if you want.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.